# gwt grid header align

Tags: java, gwt, alignment, gxt

I used to gwt 2.5.1, java 1.6.

when used grid, 
I want to centerd just grid header.
No data, Only Header.

Source

```
  .getGrid().getColumnModel().getColumns().get(i).setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

But, 
Both are aligned.

So, 
What Can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: What grid are you using `DataGrid`, `Grid`, `CellTable` ? Or some Sencha class?

Comment: package com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM inspector and fish out the style that corresponds to your header cell.
If you named your column as "test" then the style may be named something like "x-grid3-td-test".

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.x-grid3-td-test* {
text-align: center;
}
```